# "Каркасная" модель двунаправленного списка

Tags: структуры, список, очередь, двусвязный-список

Доброго времени суток. Имеется двунаправленный список, в котором есть функция (функция Swap), меняющая местами максимальный и минимальный элемент. Проблема в том, что если максимальный или минимальный элемент будет первым или последним по счету, программа не будет работать. В университете сказали, что эту проблему можно решить, если перед первым и после последнего элемента будут пустые ячейки, без информационной части. То есть первый элемент по сути становится вторым, а последний - предпоследним. Как реализовать ту самую каркасную модель?
Сам код:

```
    #include "stdafx.h"
    #include <iostream>
    #include <locale>

using namespace std;

struct Spis2 {
    int info;
    Spis2 *next, *prev;
};

void Create_Spis2(Spis2 **b, Spis2 **e, int in);
void Add_Spis2(int kod, Spis2 **b, Spis2 **e, int in);
void View_Spis2(int kod, Spis2 *t);
void Del_All(Spis2 **p);
void Funk(Spis2 **p);
void Swap(Spis2 **b,Spis2 **e);

void main() {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
    Spis2 *_begin = NULL, *_end = NULL, *t ;
    int in, kod, kod1;
    char Str[2][10] = { "начало","конец" };
    while (true) {
        cout<<"~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~" <<endl
            << "Создать - 1." << endl
            << "Добавить - 2." << endl
            << "Просмотреть - 3." << endl
            << "Удалить - 4." << endl
            << "Выход - 0." << endl
            << "Задание - 5." << endl
            << "Доп.задание - 6."<<endl
            << "~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~" << endl;
        cin >> kod;
        switch (kod) {
        case 1:
            if (_begin != NULL) {
                cout << "Очистить память" << endl;
                break;
            }
            cout << "Начало = ";
            cin >> in;
            Create_Spis2(&_begin, &_end, in);
            cout << "Создано начало = " << _begin->info << endl;
            cout << " " << endl;
            break;

        case 2:
            cout << "Введите элемент = ";
            cin >> in;
            cout << "Добавить в начало - 0, Добавить в конец - 1: ";
            cin >> kod1;
            Add_Spis2(kod1, &_begin, &_end, in);
            if (kod1 == 0) t = _begin;
            else t = _end;
            cout << "Добавлено в " << Str[kod1] << " " << t->info << endl;
            cout << " " << endl;
            break;

        case 3:
            if (!_begin) {
                cout << "Стек пуст" << endl;
                break;
            }

            cout << "Просмотр начала - 0, Просмотр конца - 1 : ";
            cin >> kod1;
            if (kod1 == 0) {
                t = _begin;
                cout << "--Начало--" << endl;
                cout << " " << endl;
            }
            else {
                t = _end;
                cout << "--Конец--" << endl;
                cout << " " << endl;
            }
            View_Spis2(kod1, t);
            break;

        case 4:
            Del_All(&_begin);
            cout << "Память освобождена!" << endl;
            break;

        case 5:
            Funk(&_begin);
            cout << "Элементы удалены!" << endl;
            cout << " " << endl;
            break;

        case 6:
            Swap(&_begin, &_end);
            cout << "Элементы перемещены!" << endl;
            break;  

        case 0:
            if (_begin != NULL)
                Del_All(&_begin);
            return;
        }
    }
}


void Create_Spis2(Spis2 **b, Spis2 **e, int in) {
    Spis2 *t = new Spis2;
    t = new Spis2;
    t->info = in;
    t->next = t->prev = NULL;
    *b = *e = t;
    return;
}

void Add_Spis2(int kod, Spis2 **b, Spis2 **e, int in) {
    Spis2 *t = new Spis2;
    t = new Spis2;
    t->info = in;
    if (kod == 0) {
        t->prev = NULL;
        t->next = *b;
        (*b)->prev = t;
        *b = t;
    }
    else {
        t->next = NULL;
        t->prev = *e;
        (*e)->next = t;
        *e = t;
    }
}

void View_Spis2(int kod, Spis2 *t) {
    while (t != NULL) {
        cout <<" "<< t->info;
        if (kod == 0) t = t->next;
        else  t = t->prev;
    }
    cout << endl;
}

void Del_All(Spis2 **p) {
    while (*p != NULL) {
        Spis2 *t = *p;
        *p = (*p)->next;
        delete t;
    }
}

void Funk(Spis2 **b) {
    Spis2 *t = *b;
    Spis2 *max = *b;
    Spis2 *min = *b;
    int x;
    while (t->next != NULL) {
        if (t->next->info > max->info) {
            max = t->next;
            x = 0;
        }

        else if (t->next->info < min->info) {
            min = t->next;
            x = 1;
        }

        else
            t = t->next;
    }
    cout << "max = " << max->info << endl;
    cout << "min = " << min->info << endl;
    if (x == 1) {
        max->next = min;
        min->prev = max;
    }
    else if (x == 0) {
        min->next = max;
        max->prev = min;
    }
}


void Swap(Spis2 **b, Spis2 **e) {
    Spis2 *t = *b;
    Spis2 *pMax = *b;
    Spis2 *pMin = *b;
    Spis2 *max = *b;
    Spis2 *min = *b;
    int x;
    while (t->next != NULL) {
        if (t->next->info > max->info) {
            max = t->next;
            x = 0;
        }

        else if (t->next->info < min->info) {
            min = t->next;
            x = 1;
        }

        else
            t = t->next;
    }
    cout << "Max = " << max->info << endl;
    cout << "Min = " << min->info << endl;

    if (x == 0) {       
        Spis2* prevMin = min->prev;
        Spis2* nextMin = min->next;
        min->prev->next = max;
        min->next->prev = max;
        min->next = max->next;
        min->prev = max->prev;
        max->prev->next = min;
        max->next->prev = min;
        max->prev = prevMin;
        max->next = nextMin;        
        }

    else {
        Spis2* prevMax = max->prev;
        Spis2* nextMax = max->next;
        max->prev->next = min;
        max->next->prev = min;
        max->next = min->next;
        max->prev = min->prev;
        min->prev->next = max;
        min->next->prev = max;
        min->prev = prevMax;
        min->next = nextMax;
    }       
}
```

Comment: Да, все правильно сказали в университете. Операции на списке становятся проще, если не нужно отдельно логически выделять первый и последний элемент. Поэтому перед первым создается нулевой элемент, которому не соответствуют никакие данные, и такой же элемент после последнего. Первоначально в пустом списке эти элементы просто указывают друг на друга, а результат такой: при вставке или удалении элемента списка вам не нужно проверять, является ли он первым или последним.

Comment: И как создать эти самые элементы?